# Print function print some strange chars

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, random

i'm trying to create a random strings using this function:

```
static char *rand_string(char *str)
{   
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJK";
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof charset - 1);
        str[i] = charset[key];
    }
        str[11] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

The problem is this: sometimes when i am going to print the pointer, it display some strange char like this:
[image: bug]
As you can see in the first launch the chars in a string are 10, in the second and third launch the chars in a string are 11...

This is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static char *rand_string(char *str);


int main() 
{

    char *string, //str
         *string_result; //str1


    int dimensione= 15,
        i;

    for(i=0;i<dimensione;i++)
    {
        string_result = rand_string(string);
        printf("%s\n", string_result);

    }
}


static char *rand_string(char *str)
{   
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJK";
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof charset - 1);
        str[i] = charset[key];
    }
        str[11] = '\0';

    return str;
}
```

You can view and test my code here --> https://onlinegdb.com/r1yY8DWc8

Comment: Did you choose the correct index to end the string in `rand_string`?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `str[10] = '\0'`

Comment: @PeterO. i guess so ...

Comment: @Inian can you explain please ?

Comment: @Inian you remove the code, but it was the correct way to do it! Thank you man, i have took it, but we could share it with the community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole code invoke undefined behavior, because you are passing `string` which is an uninitialized pointer which may "not" be guaranteed to accessible for the 11 bytes your are accessing in the `rand_string()` function.

You need to allocate memory from the `main()` and pass that buffer to be filled by the random string generator function, that way you have control of the memory you are modifying.

Also the `for` loop in your generator already fills indices from `0` to `9`. To set the final byte to NULL, you need to use the index as 10.

Also the headers `time.h` and `unistd.h` are useless here. Here is a re-write of the same program with memory allocated through `malloc()`. Also modified your function `rand_string()` to void instead of returning a string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void rand_string(char *str);


int main() 
{

    int dimensione= 15;

    char *string = malloc(11 * sizeof *string); // extra byte for NULL

    if (!string) return 1;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<dimensione;i++)
    {
        rand_string(string);
        printf("%s\n", string);
    }

    free(string);
    return 0;
}


void rand_string(char *str)
{   
    const char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJK";
    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
    {
        int key = rand() % (int) (sizeof charset - 1);
        str[i] = charset[key];
    }
        str[10] = '\0';
}
```

Always compile with extra flags to enable all sorts of warnings from your compiler. For e.g. with `gcc` always add `-Wall -Wextra` to see the warnings that you could fix from your side.

Comment: Hey, Thank you for have rewrite my code! It is really helpful! Unfortunately, i can use only one "return" per function... how "we" could fix it?

Comment: Wait ... i can use ELSE instead of return 1 !

Comment: Thank you man, that is the right way for do it! My code was a shit :D

Comment: Hey man, last stuff just for understand. I need to catch the result value of function "rand_string"... i declared it as: char *rand_string(char *str).

and i have added "return str;" in the end ... that's mean i just need to declar a char pointer and i can catch the return value ?

Comment: You don't have to return a string for your requirement. But if you still insist, you can do as you said. But I wouldn't do it design it that way

Comment: I need to catch the result for use the string obtained in another function ... that's why i need the return!